# Javascript- share selected image on facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, file-upload

I am building an app using Visual Studio, and I want to allow my users to share an image on their Facebook group.
I have managed to share an image by URL but I want to let my users upload photos from their own device, so I tried to put a "file input" and send selected image to Facebook's code:

```
function ShareLink() {
FB.ui(
{   display: 'popup',
    **picture: fileBTN.value**,
    method: 'share',
}, function (response) { });
```

It didn't work.

** Since sharing has been successfully done with a URL, maybe I could upload an image to server (after been selected by a user) and then write its URL in Facebook's code.

I have tried both solutions but couldn't make it.
Thanks a lot for any assistance!
Asaf.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `/me/photos` endpoint to post a photo on Facebook instead of just sharing an URL. The user needs to be authorized with the `publish_actions` permission for that. Example code and more information can be found in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/user/photos#Creating